# Rust Tokio mpsc::channel unexpected behavior for multi-task program

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

In the following program I use Tokio's mpsc channels. The Sender is moved to a task named `input_message` and the Receiver is moved to another task named `printer`. Both tasks are `tokio::spawn()`-ed in the main function. The `input_message` task is to read the user's input and send it through a Channel. The `printer` task `recv()` on the channel to get the user's input and simply prints it to stdout:

```
use std::error::Error;
use tokio::sync::mpsc;
use std::io::{BufRead, Write};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::unbounded_channel::<String>();

    let printer = tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            let res = rx.recv().await;          // (11) Comment this ..
            // let res = rx.try_recv();         // (12) Uncomment this ,,
            if let Some(m) = res {              // .. and this
            // if let Ok(m) = res {             // ,, and this
                if m.trim() == "q".to_string() {
                    break;
                } 
                println!("Received: {}", m.trim());
            }
        }
        println!("Printer exited");
    });

    let input_message = tokio::spawn(async move {
        let stdin = std::io::stdin();
        let mut bufr = std::io::BufReader::new(stdin);
        let mut buf = String::new();
        loop {
            // Let the printer thread print the string before asking the user's input.
            std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1));
            print!("Enter input: ");
            std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
            bufr.read_line(&mut buf).unwrap();

            if buf.trim() == "q".to_string() {
                tx.send(buf).unwrap();
                break;
            }
            tx.send(buf).unwrap();

            buf = String::new();
        }
        println!("InputMessage exited");
    });   

    tokio::join!(input_message, printer);
    Ok(())
}
```

The expected behavior of the program is to:

1. Ask the user a random input (q to quit)
2. Print that same input to stdout

Using `rx.recv().await` as in line 11-13 the program seems to buffer the Strings representing the user's input: the various inputs are not received by the `printer` task that therefore does not print the strings to stdout. Once the quit message (i.e. q) is sent, the `input_message` task exits and the messages seems to be flushed out of the channel and the receiver processes them all at once, and so the `printer` task prints all the inputs at once. Here's an example of wrong output:

```
Enter input: Hello
Enter input: World
Enter input: q
InputMessage exited
Received: Hello
Received: World
Printer exited
```

My question here is, how is it possible that the channel buffers the messages and processes them in one go only when the sending thread exits, instead of receiving them as they are sent?

What I tried to do is to use the `try_recv()` function as in line 12-14 and indeed it fixes the problem. The output is correctly printed, here is an example:

```
Enter input: Hello
Received: Hello
Enter input: World
Received: World
Enter input: q
InputMessage exited
Printer exited
```

In light of this, I get confused. I get the difference between the `recv().await` and the `try_recv()` functions but I think there's something more in this case that I'm ignoring that makes the latter work and the former not work. Is anybody able to shed some light and elaborate on this? Why does `try_recv()` work and `recv().await` not, and why should `recv().await` not work in this scenario? In terms of efficiency is looping on `try_recv()` bad or "bad practice" at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to point out here, but first of all, you are waiting for lines on `std::io::stdin()` which blocks the thread until a line arrives on that stream. While the thread waiting for input, no other future can be executed on this thread, [this blog post](https://ryhl.io/blog/async-what-is-blocking/) is a great resource if you want to dive deeper why you shouldn't do that.

Tokio's `io` module offers an async handle to `stdin()`, you can work with this as a quick fix, although [the documentation explicitly mentions](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/src/tokio/io/stdin.rs.html#35-42) that you should spin up a dedicated (non-async) thread for interactive user input instead of using the async handle.

Swapping `std::io::stdin()` for `tokio::io::stdin()` also entails swapping out the standard library `BufReader` for tokio's implementation that wraps an `R: AsyncRead` rather than `R: Read`.

To prevent interleaved writes between the input task and the output task, you can use a responder channel that signals to the input task when the output has been printed. Instead of sending `String` over the channel, you could send a `Message` with these fields:

```
struct Message {
    payload: String,
    done_tx: oneshot::Sender<()>,
}
```

After reading an input line, send the `Message` over the channel to the printer task. The printer task prints the `String` and signals through the `done_tx` that the input task can print the input prompt and wait for a new line.

Putting all that together with some other changes like a while loop to wait for messages, you'd end up with something like this:

```
use std::error::Error;
use tokio::io::{AsyncBufReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};
use tokio::sync::{mpsc, oneshot};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Message {
    done_tx: oneshot::Sender<()>,
    message: String,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::unbounded_channel::<Message>();

    let printer = tokio::spawn(async move {
        while let Some(Message {
            message: m,
            done_tx,
        }) = rx.recv().await
        {
            if m.trim() == "q".to_string() {
                break;
            }
            println!("Received: {}", m.trim());
            done_tx.send(()).unwrap();
        }
        println!("Printer exited");
    });

    let input_message = tokio::spawn(async move {
        let stdin = tokio::io::stdin();
        let mut stdout = tokio::io::stdout();
        let mut bufr = tokio::io::BufReader::new(stdin);
        let mut buf = String::new();
        loop {
            // Let the printer thread print the string before asking the user's input.
            stdout.write(b"Enter input: ").await.unwrap();
            stdout.flush().await.unwrap();
            bufr.read_line(&mut buf).await.unwrap();

            let end = buf.trim() == "q";
            let (done_tx, done) = oneshot::channel();
            let message = Message {
                message: buf,
                done_tx,
            };
            tx.send(message).unwrap();
            if end {
                break;
            }
            done.await.unwrap();

            buf = String::new();
        }
        println!("InputMessage exited");
    });

    tokio::join!(input_message, printer);
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. To be clear, what I reported is the minimal program that reproduces the behavior I can't really understand. In the project I am working on, instead of using the `std::io::stdin` I use the `termion` async_stdin [link](https://docs.rs/termion/latest/termion/fn.async_stdin.html). Although reading it is not a future you await on. How comes the `recv().await` is not run while the `async_stdin` does not block? I don't know if you can answer this question without context that I don't know if I'm able to provide in this space.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to achieve is have a thread/task dedicated to read from a TcpConnection and a thread/task read the interactive user's input. The printer thread/task will print according to what it receives from the server or the users input. The reason why I opted to avoid using tokio async stdio  is exactly the warning they say in their docs as I need interactive user interaction. What they suggest is to spin up a thread, so this means a native thread outside the tokio environment (`std::thread::spawn()` vs `tokio::spawn()`) right?

Comment: And one last thing, I have a feeling the solution I found in the post (using `try_recv()`) is spurious. I feel like it's a bad way of doing what I'm trying to do, would you agree with that, or do you think such a solution is acceptable. If not, could you explain why? 
Thank you.